# Meteor + Sequelize. Will they work together?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, orm, meteor, sequelize.js

According to Meteor [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/),

> Today most Meteor apps use MongoDB as their database because it is the
>   best supported, though support for other databases is coming in the
>   future.

Also there is a great SQL ORM for Node — [Sequelize](http://sequelizejs.com/)

The question is: will Meteor and Sequelize combination work? Is it worth spending time on mixing them in one app? Or Meteor's Collection class tightly relies on MongoDB and it will be too complicated to implement Sequelize backend with it?

Comment: You would need a non-trivial amount of work to make sequelize do the same Meteor already does with MongoDB. So the answer is "Yes, they can potentially work together", but in reality it is a very big task to accomplish.

Comment: It's too bad Meteor is so wedded to MongoDB only.  MongoDB is good as solution to a very narrow subset of problems, but there are many more problems better addressed by a traditional relational structure.  Even as an object store, MongoDB leaves much to be desired, as it doesn't quite represent enough flexibility in terms of how you group objects.  The lack of any notion of a schema -- particularly when materializing stored data into a real in-memory object -- leads to a lot of management overhead.

Comment: After some time spent on development of Meteor based application I realize that Mongo is the only one feasible solution for now. Meteor is a system that shares significant parts of code and behavior between client and server. And there is a database abstraction layer on the client side. It's called MiniMongo. I cannot imagine possible implementation of SQL driver on the client side. But Mongo fits in just perfectly. So you actually have to change the way you think about DB for your Meteor app.